# Min in where clause in group using Row_Number() over order by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below query which selects data from table COE3REL1. In the select statement it converts cyymmdd to yyyy-mm-dd. On the screen shot the table on the left is what is outputted current and table on the right is the desired outcome. I need to amend the where clause so it only selects the min id number in the group of Subscription E3BXDT. I am able to do this by outputting creating a table, and then writing a group by and select min (ID) from created table, however i need to action in 1 sql query.

Any support would be appreciated

Thanks

```
select 
E3B8NB as "Subscription"    
,date((((int(E3BXDT)/10000)+1900)|| '-' ||
(MOD(int(E3BXDT),10000) /100)|| '-' ||
MOD(int(E3BXDT),100)))  "ST Effective Date" 
,E3B6CD as "Tariff"
,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by E3B8NB) as ID
from  DISEBTRD.COE3REL1
where E3BXDT > 1000000 
order by E3B8NB,E3BXDT desc
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Sami its not SQL_Server i use an application called Lavastorm where you write SQL statements to draw data from ISeries, but usual sql_server queries work the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try putting your query in a cte and then selecting where the row number = 1. You can try the following:

```
with maindata as (
select 
        E3B6CD as "Tariff"
    ,   E3B8NB as "Subscription"
    ,   date((((int(E3BXDT)/10000)+1900)|| '-' ||
        (MOD(int(E3BXDT),10000) /100)|| '-' ||
        MOD(int(E3BXDT),100)))  "ST Effective Date" 
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by E3B8NB order by E3BXDT asc) as ID
from  DISEBTRD.COE3REL1
where E3BXDT > 1000000 
)
select * from maindata 
where id=1
order by Subscription,[ST Effective Date] desc
```

Answer (score 0):

A row_number with a partition on the Subscription could help here.
And then wrap it in a sub-query, and filter in the outer-query.

```
SELECT 
  Subscription
, "ST Effective Date"
, Tariff
, ID
FROM
(
    SELECT E3B8NB AS Subscription
    , date(int(E3BXDT)+19000000) AS "ST Effective Date" 
    , E3B6CD AS Tariff
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY E3B8NB, E3BXDT) AS ID
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY E3B8NB ORDER BY E3BXDT) AS RN
    FROM DISEBTRD.COE3REL1
    WHERE E3BXDT > 1000000
) q
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: Thanks @Lukstorms Select statement didnt work but amending this to select * from worked perfectly Thanks

Comment: Thx.  Btw, I've been wondering about that long ass calculation for the effective date.  I assume E3BXDT contains strings like '1191231'.  But some databases can cast a string like '20191213' to a DATE type.  So do you think that `date(int(E3BXDT)+19000000)` could work also?

Comment: Hi @LukStorm yes the calculation changes cyymmdd to yyyy-mm-dd, if i was using SQL sever i would use convert however using an application called Lavastorm that draws data from iseries doesnt have that functionality

Comment: Thx for the feedback.  Succesfull golf-code get! ;)